# Prove that $\{m \in M \mid mam^{-1} \in A, \ \forall a \in A\}$ forms a subgroup of M.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-writing

I am given a group $M$ with identity element $1$, and $A$ $\leq$ $M$. I am then given a set $G = \{m \in M \mid mam^{-1} \in A, \ \forall a \in A\}$ and asked to prove that $G \leq M$.

I am confused about both the closure and identity.

Attempt for proving closure:

Let $g$, $h$ be two elements in $G$ such that $gag^{-1} \in A$ and $hah^{-1}$ $\in$ $A$. Then I have to show that $(gh)a(gh)^{-1}$ $\in$ $A$ for the same $a \in A$, right?
Here is what I tried:

Take $(gh)a(gh)^{-1} \implies (gh)a(h^{-1}g^{-1})$ $\implies$ $g(hah^{-1})g^{-1}$. Now, I am confused because $hah^{-1}$ $\in A$, but it is not necessarily equal to $a$ which means, if I say $hah^{-1} = b \in A$ then I get, $gbg^{-1} \in A$. What I am not sure is I started with the assumption that the element $a$ must be the same. What am I misunderstanding here?

Comment: It isn't clear what $a$ means in your definition of  $G$, as opposed to  $A$.

Comment: This is false generally, unless $A$ is finite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can only presume the subset $G$ should have been written as $$G = \{m \in M: mam^{-1} \in A \quad \forall a \in A\}.$$
Then arguing as you do you run into no barriers, as you correctly identified that $hah^{-1} \in A$, so then so too $ghah^{-1}g^{-1} \in A$, and $G$ is closed.

I'll leave you to consider why $G$ is closed under taking inverses.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Could you see if my work for closure under inverses makes sense? So I took $m \in M$ such that $mam^{-1} \in A \forall a \in A$. Since $A$ $\leq$ $M$, $mam^{-1} \in A \forall a \in A$ $\implies$ $(mam^{-1})^{-1}$ $\in$ $A$. But that does not lead me anywhere, does it? How should I approach this?

Comment: Does it not? $(mam^{-1})^{-1} = m^{-1}a^{-1}m$, so if this is in $A$ for all $a \in A$ (and necessarily all $a^{-1} \in A$, since $A \leq M$), then doesn't that say $m^{-1} \in M$, which is precisely what you want to show?

Comment: But isn’t $(mam^{-1})^{-1} = ma^{-1}m^{-1}$ using the inverse rule for products of elements in a group?

Comment: Sorry, yes, you're quite right, let me rethink.

Comment: If $m \in G$ then $mam^{-1} \in A \quad \forall a \in A$. Now $m^{-1}(mam^{-1})m \in A$ for all $a \in A$ (you will need to convince yourself why all $mam^{-1} \in A$ give all $a \in A$), so $m^{-1} \in G$ as required.

Comment: Just a quick question. So I see why $mam^{-1} \in A$ gives all $a \in A$ cause $A$ is a subgroup of $M$ and since $M$ is a group and is closed, $mam^{-1} \in M$. And since all elements of M are obtained that way, all elements of A are also obtained. What I am struggling to see is: Is it possible for $mam^{-1}$ to produce elements other than that in $A$?

Comment: Not if $m \in G$! If $m \in M \setminus G$ then yes

Answer (score 1):

$G$ is called the [normalizer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centralizer_and_normalizer) of $A$. You are on the right track.

If $g, h \in G$, then $gAg^{-1}=A$ and $hAh^{-1}=A$. So, $$ghA(gh)^{-1}=ghAh^{-1}g^{-1}=gAg^{-1}=A.$$ Thus, $gh \in G$.

If $g \in G$, then $gAg^{-1}=A$ and thus $A=g^{-1}Ag$. So, $g^{-1} \in G$.

Comment: So you mean, notationwise, the set {$m \in M| mam^{-1} \in A, \forall a \in A$} is same as the set {$m \in M | mAm^{-1} = A$}?

Comment: @Ufomammut These are not equivalent when $A$ is infinite. The second set is the normalizer of $A$, not the first. In fact, the first need not be a subgroup.

Comment: @CuriousKid7, thank you. Also, even if $A$ is finite, let's say then the two sets in my first comment are not equal, are they?

Comment: @Ufomammut they are equal in that case

Comment: @CuriousKid7 do you mind explaining why they are not equal if $A$ is infinite.