# Proving that the inverse exists in the given set to verify subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-writing

This question is a follow-up to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3147325/proof-that-the-given-subset-forms-a-subgroup) question. I am still not understanding how I can show more rigorously that $m^{-1}$ exists in G, in which case I have to prove that $m^{-1}am \in G  \forall  a \in A$. Does anyone have a more rigorous way of showing it that what the comments in the answer have?
In particular, the answerer comments "If $m \in G$ then $mam^{−1} \in A \forall a\in A$. Now $m^{−1}(mam^{−1})m \in A$ for all $a \in A$ (you will need to convince yourself why all $mam^{−1} \in A$ give all $a \in A$), so $m^{−1} \in G$ as required." How do I show that all elements in $A$ can be expressed as the product $mam^{-1}$?

Edit 1: Few things I have been asking myself recently is: Does the above proof mean exactly the same as proving $mAm^{-1} = A$ where $m \in M$? In that case, I have to show i) $mAm^{-1} \subseteq A$ and ii) $A \subseteq mAm^{-1}$. Number i) should be easy cause if $m \in M$, then $mam^{-1} \in A \forall a \in A$, which means  $mAm^{-1} \subseteq A$. I do not know how to prove number ii) though.

Answer (score 1):

The definition of $G$ is
$$
G=\{m\in M\mid mam^{-1}\in A\text{, for all }a\in A\}
$$
The fact that $1\in G$ is obvious. Proving closure under products is easy: suppose $m,n\in G$ and $a\in A$; then, for $a\in A$,
$$
(mn)a(mn)^{-1}=m(nan^{-1})m^{-1}
$$
By definition, $b=nan^{-1}\in A$, so also $mbm^{-1}\in A$.

Now your question. If $m\in G$ and $a\in A$, then $mam^{-1}\in A$; therefore $mAm^{-1}\subseteq A$. You can't generally prove that $mAm^{-1}=A$, see [Conjugate subgroup strictly contained in the initial subgroup?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/107862/conjugate-subgroup-strictly-contained-in-the-initial-subgroup)

The statement you have to prove requires more hypotheses, for instance that $A$ is *finite*, because in this case $mAm^{-1}$ has the same cardinality as $A$ and, being a subset thereof, they're equal.

If $a\in A\setminus mAm^{-1}$, then $m^{-1}am\in A$ would imply $a\in mAm^{-1}$: contradiction.

If we change the definition of $G$ to be
$$
G=\{m\in M\mid mAm^{-1}=A\}
$$
then $G$ is a subgroup of $M$.

Comment: For me, this has raised more questions. How is the new definition of G that you have mentioned at the end of your answer going to help in the verification of the original question? If I did not get it wrong, are you suggesting that the fact that A is not mentioned in the question to be finite, there is no way to prove $mAm^{-1} = A$ and hence no way to prove that $m^{-1}$ exists in G?

Comment: @Ufomammut The original question states a false theorem.

Comment: so would it be true if $A$ were mentioned to be finite?

Comment: @Ufomammut Yes, that would be sufficient.